# How to create a proxy download in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, proxy, download

I want to create a nodejs server which is acting a proxy to download files i.e. user clicks 
on the a download button, call get from nodejs server, nodejs server fetches link from a different 
remote server and starts the download (in terabytes). This download is then forwarded to the user.
The terabyte file should not be stored on the nodejs server and then sent.

Here is my attempt:

```
function (request, response) {

 // anything related to the remote server having the file
 var options= {
        path: "./bigData",
        hostname:"www.hugeFiles.net"
    }

    // get the file from the remote server hugefiles and push to user's response
    https.get(options, function(downFile)) {
        downFile.pipe(response) 
    }

}
```

Before I was using `res.download(file, function(err)) {}` but file has to be downloaded completely from the remote server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're very close, you're sending the right http body but with the wrong http headers.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const app1 = express();

app1.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.download('server.js');
});

app1.listen(8000);

const app2 = express();

app2.get('/', function (req, res) {
  http.get({ path: '/', hostname: 'localhost', port: 8000}, function (resp) {
    res.setHeader('content-disposition', resp.headers['content-disposition']);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', resp.headers['content-type']);
    resp.pipe(res);
  });
});

app2.listen(9000);
```

Though I would say you should take a look at modules like https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy which take care of the header etc . . . for you.

Comment: a) Would the user be able to see the link being downloaded on the proxy server? b) If I use harrypotter.scholastic.com/excerpts/HP_Book1_Chapter_Excerpt.pdf  where hostname is harrypotter.scholastic.com and path "/excerpts/HP_Book1_Chapter_Excerpt.pdf" the download is not triggered in the user's browser. Do you know why?

Comment: a) Not unless you put it in the headers

Comment: b) It tried it with that url, the headers don't have a content-disposition, just a content-type

Comment: Nice solution, also please supply your code by adding line below:
res.setHeader('Content-type', resp.headers['content-type']);

Comment: how to use POST with http in this scenario?

Comment: The story is pretty much the same for post.  The difference is that for post you need to also stream the post body down to the backend.  Something like `const post = http.post...; req.pipe(post);` the headers and response body piping is the same.

Answer (score -6):

There is no way for your server to provide a file to the client without the server downloading it first.

What you may want to do instead is provide the client with a download link to the huge file. To make it seem automatic, you can create html which starts a download from the content provider automatically and serve that to the client.

In other words, in the scenario you are describing, the server is acting as a middleman between your client and the content provider. Unless the server needs to process the data or the client isn't allowed to retrieve the data themselves, it makes more sense to cut out the middleman.