# How to fetch remote PDF from a url and send to the client with Express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side

I would like to fetch a pdf from a URL and send it to the client in an Express (JS) application via a REST endpoint. However, most resources are focused on sending a PDF file located on the local file system.

Comment: Did you look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280876/how-to-create-a-proxy-download-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that works great.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const url = 'https://example.com/file';
const fileName = 'pdf-file';

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const stream = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename=${fileName}.pdf`);
  return stream.data.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```